# Find the image of $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|\leq1 \ \text{and}\ 0\leq \text{arg}\ z <\pi\}$ under $f (z)=z^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Let $f(z) = z^2$. Find the image of $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|\leq1 \ \text{and}\ 0\leq \text{arg}\ z <\pi\}$ under $f$.

My attempt: If we draw $D$ then we get $D = \ \text{the upper half disk}\ \setminus [-1,0)$.

Let $z = re^{i\theta}$ where $r\in [0,1]$ and $\theta \in [0, \pi)$. Hence,  $w=z^2 = r^2 e^{2i\theta}$. Take $\rho= r^2$ and $\alpha = 2\theta$.

We clearly see that $\rho \in [0,1]$ and $\alpha  \in [0, 2\pi)$.

Hence the image would be $\bar{\Delta} = \{z\in \mathbb{c} : |z|\leq 1\}$.

Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that looks good!

Comment: Correct. Maybe, just for clarification purposes, make explictily clear that indeed if $w\in D$ there is $z' \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $(z')^2 = w$